# Permutation generation code in Go using a shared 'temp' slice exhibits unexpected behavior with input sizes less than 3

Tags: arrays, go, memory-management, reference, slice

```
func permute(nums []int) [][]int {
    return gen(nums, [][]int{}, []int{}, make([]bool, len(nums)));
}

func gen(nums []int, res [][]int, temp []int, used []bool) [][]int {
    if len(nums) == len(temp) {
        //ctemp := make([]int, len(temp))
        //copy(ctemp, temp)
        return append(res, temp)
    } 
    for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
        if !used[i] {
            used[i] = true
            temp = append(temp, nums[i])
            res = gen(nums, res, temp, used)
            temp = temp[:len(temp) - 1]
            used[i] = false
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

The above function is able to generate all the permutation correctly
when the length of the input slice is 1,2 or 3
but on input size greater than 3 the 1d slice have same value
so to correct this issue i create a copy of the int slice and then append that to the 2d result slice

but why does the above code works for input size less than 4
since a slice have a backing array so after appending to the 2d res slice
any modification to the temp 1d slice should be reflected on 2d slice res
since it is pointing to the same backing array
why is this behavior not present in input slice of size 2 and 3 ?

input -> [1,2,3]  output -> [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]

input -> [5,4,6,2] output -> [[5,4,2,6],[5,4,2,6],[5,6,2,4],[5,6,2,4],[5,2,6,4],[5,2,6,4],[4,5,2,6],[4,5,2,6],[4,6,2,5],[4,6,2,5],[4,2,6,5],[4,2,6,5],[6,5,2,4],[6,5,2,4],[6,4,2,5],[6,4,2,5],[6,2,4,5],[6,2,4,5],[2,5,6,4],[2,5,6,4],[2,4,6,5],[2,4,6,5],[2,6,4,5],[2,6,4,5]]

why is it working on input [1,2,3]

Comment: It probably works because of some random capacity thing that makes it work. Nothing to see here. Just fix the code.